# Change size of paper-toggle-button

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am new in Polymer,

I have added paper-toggle-button in my project.I found css classes on official website to change color and transition animation. However I want to reduce it in size especially by some pixels.

I have search through web. But did not successes.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

you can change the size by applying mixins, add the following code to your css styles

```
paper-toggle-button {
    --paper-toggle-button-unchecked-button: {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    --paper-toggle-button-unchecked-bar: {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
}
```